# putting an xls file in a jar

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, jar, metamodel

I have an xls spreadsheet that I'm querying using metaModel, and I want to keep the xls file in the jar, because it won't be updated. The method used for creating the data context doesn't allow inputstreams, I tried using this code:

```
DataContext dataContext = DataContextFactory.createExcelDataContext(getClass().getResourceAsStream("database.xls"));
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, as the method createExcelDataContext doesn't take inputstreams as a parameter. Is there any way to keep the file in the jar?

It seems the easiest way to do this is just export to csv, as this is easily done.

Comment: What does the DataContext allow? Which DataContext API are you using?

Comment: Also, what IDE and compiler are you using?

Comment: @anders.norgaard It only allows a file object, and I just downloaded and installed from here: http://metamodel.eobjects.org/

Comment: @gobernador I'm using eclipse

Comment: @Mukhi one thing that I've done is create a `/res` subpackage and keep all my non-java files in there. I think you can just navigate to the package location with Windows Explorer and paste the excel document in there. It's worked for me in the past.

Comment: @gobernador I'll try, but will this allow others to access it if I just give someone a jar?

Comment: Yes, it should. I've used this technique to install drivers and other important files. It should be compiled into the jar and then you can access it with `Class.getResourceAsStream()` or `Class.getResource()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that other kinds of contexts can be created from an InputStream, I would guess that it's a limitation of Excel, and that you won't be able to open the Excel file if it isn't on the file system.

Consider extracting the file from the jar and copy its content to a temporary file, possibly deleted when the application ends. See [File.createTempFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [File.deleteOnExit()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: but how would I put the file in the jar?

Comment: How are you building the jar file?

Comment: nevermind, I decided to convert the file to csv, and use the inputstream from there, as xls files are easily exported to csv.

Comment: So you know how to put a CSV file in a jar, but not an XLS file? What's the differene? A file is a file.

Comment: Well with the cab I can use the getResourceAsStream method and it automatically adds it to the manifest, and keeps it in the jar. Can't do that with the xls

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make much sense. getResourceAsStream() gets a resource, at runtime, from the classpath. It doesn't have anything to do with a manifest, and doesn't add anything to it. If you build procedure adds the xls file to the jar, there is no problem accessing it with getResourceAsStream(). A jar is just a zip file. You can put wahtever file you want in it.

Comment: when I put an xls file inside the jar, it doesn't launch, because there's no classpath in the manifest. when I put a csv it does the same, unless I use the getResourcesAsStream method, so I'm just assuming it automatically updates everything for me, as it anticipates it needs the file at runtime from inside the jar.

Comment: Besides which, that isn't the point. converting to csv, then adding it to the source folder, and using the one method, is clearly easier then whatever was going to happen. besides which, it's better for my situation to keep the file inside the jar, than create a temporary file, then delete it.

Comment: I repeat: the manifest has nothing to do with getResourceAsStream(). If the jar is in the classpath, and if the file is in the jar, getResourceAsStream() will find it, whatever the type or name of the file is. That said, what is your question now? Shouldn't you close it, since my answer doesn't suit you, and you don't seem to be interested in any other answer anyway?

Comment: I can't because you've answered it. I've already flagged it for deletion, can't do anything else.